# Should I let recruiter know that I was interviewed with his company in the past?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, ethics

I was interviewed and rejected by a company (branch A) a couple of years ago. Now I am approached by another recruiter from a different branch (branch B). After a short discussion she suggested to connect me with a recruiter from branch A and apply there. Should I tell them about the first interview and rejection? (The position I would be applying now is not the same as it was for the first time.)

Comment: Ultimately, employers who would care to know if you've applied before will likely either be keeping their own records of who has applied, or they'll put a question on the job application asking you to tell them. No employer who cares about this will rely on an applicant voluntarily disclosing this without being prompted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A rejection is normally a rejection for that role, at that time, in that team, from that interviewer.

This is a different role, at a later date, and you have a couple of years more experience and have learned more skills. The earlier interview will probably have no impact on this application at all. So **do not mention it**. It's irrelevant.

The only exception would be if the interviewer thought you were absolutely terrible and could not imagine ever working with you, under any circumstances, in their entire career. If that's the case, they'll probably remember who you are, and reject your application before it even gets as far as an interview. So you still don't need to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

> *Should I tell them about the first interview and rejection?*

Is there anything in the application form / process that needs you to disclose this information? If not, then there is nothing useful can be achieved by having that info. The time and the positions are vastly different.

**Let them ask if they want to know.**

Answer (score 0):

Well, depends. I've had that happen in the past and I would let that depend on the experience with the company at the time.

If the interview with the company, at the time, went along the lines of:

- not currently a fit (with (f)actual reasons)
- not yet skilled enough (with (f)actual reasons)
- maybe next year

But through it all it was decent, pleasant and informative, then, no, would not tell them and go for round to.

If it was a bit more towards

- need you to do task X to prove competence
- sit with non-techies to talk shop
- see that they're not really looking for a new hire

Then, yes, would say had an interview, would mention I didn't like the place and won't go there again.

---

Really would depend on what you want and your previous experience with said company.

Answer (score -1):

No, you don't **have** to, but they may consult their own records or one person may remember your application... for better or worse...